# How to change font size h1 - h6 with button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, fonts

I'm trying to change the font size by clicking on a button, going from 16px to 18px or vice versa. So with css I defined the styles from h1 to h6 in two different scales.

I know I can play with Javascript and assign the different classes I have created to the h1 and h6 tags, but I have no idea where to start. For now I only have html and css. Can any Good Samaritan help me by showing me a way to do this?

In fact, I don't even know if it's the correct way to define styles and then apply them to tags. Sorry but I'm new, I appreciate any response.

```css
/*16px Major Third 1.250 Scale Factor*/
.main_container > h1 {
  font-size: 31.25px;
}

.main_container > h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.main_container > h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main_container > h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main_container > h5 {
  font-size: 12.8px;
}

.main_container > h6 {
  font-size: 10.24px;
}

.main_container > p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

/*18px Major Third 1.250 Scale Factor*/
.main_container > h1 {
 font-size: 35.16px;
}

.main_container > h2 {
 font-size: 28.13;
}

.main_container > h3 {
  font-size: 22.5px;
}

.main_container > h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
}

.main_container > h5 {
 font-size: 14.4;
}

.main_container > h6 {
  font-size: 11.52;
}

.main_container > p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<button class="regular">Set 16px Typography</button>
<button class="regular">Set 18px Typography</button>

<div class="main_container">
  <h1>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h1>
  <h2>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h2>
  <h3>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h3>
  <h4>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h4>
  <h5>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h5>
  <h6>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h6>
  <p>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is already provided for in the CSS specifications, it is the relative units.
here you have to use `em` unit, --> all font- sizes will be relative to their parent

doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

sample code:

```js
function set_font_size_big(test)
  {
  document.querySelectorAll('.main_container').forEach( el =>
    el.classList.toggle('big',test))
  }
```

```css
.main_container      { font-size  : 16px;  }
.main_container.big  { font-size  : 18px;  }

.main_container > h1 { font-size: 1.95em; }
.main_container > h2 { font-size: 1.56em; }
.main_container > h3 { font-size: 1.25em; }
.main_container > h4 { font-size: 1em;    }
.main_container > h5 { font-size: 0.8em;  }
.main_container > h6 { font-size: 0.64em; }
```

```html
<button onclick="set_font_size_big(false)"> normal (16px) </button>
<button onclick="set_font_size_big(true)"> big (18px) </button>

<div class="main_container">
  <h1>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h1>
  <h2>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h2>
  <h3>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h3>
  <h4>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h4>
  <h5>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h5>
  <h6>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h6>
  <p>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</div>
```

But the best would be to use a CSS variable, which saves you from having to add / remove the big class on each of your `.main_container` elements
doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

and which gives you more possibilities, like here with a range type input

```js
const
  Root            = document.documentElement
, fontSizRange    = document.querySelector('#font_size_range')
, fontSizRangeVal = document.querySelector('#font_size_range + label')
, sizelabel = 
  { 14 : 'small'
  , 16 : 'normal'
  , 18 : 'big'
  , 20 : 'biggest'
  , 22 : 'enormous'
  }  ;

function setFontSize()
  {
  fontSizRangeVal.textContent = sizelabel[ fontSizRange.value ]
  Root.style.setProperty('--mc_f_size', fontSizRange.value + 'px' )
  }

  setFontSize()  // init
fontSizRange.oninput = setFontSize
```

```css
:Root { --mc_f_size: 16px; }

.main_container  { font-size : var(--mc_f_size); }

.main_container > h1 { font-size: 1.95em; }
.main_container > h2 { font-size: 1.56em; }
.main_container > h3 { font-size: 1.25em; }
.main_container > h4 { font-size: 1em;    }
.main_container > h5 { font-size: 0.8em;  }
.main_container > h6 { font-size: 0.64em; }
```

```html
<input type="range" id="font_size_range" min="14" max="22" step="2" value="16"><label></label>

<div class="main_container">
  <h1>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h1>
  <h2>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h2>
  <h3>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h3>
  <h4>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h4>
  <h5>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h5>
  <h6>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h6>
  <p>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</div>
```

---

> **PO** comment:  Last doubt, could I replace the range slider with buttons? I am trying to do this based on your example but I cannot.

```js
function set_font_size( val )
  {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mc_f_size', val + 'px' )
  }
```

```css
:Root { --mc_f_size: 16px; }

.main_container  { font-size : var(--mc_f_size); }

.main_container > h1 { font-size: 1.95em; }
.main_container > h2 { font-size: 1.56em; }
.main_container > h3 { font-size: 1.25em; }
.main_container > h4 { font-size: 1em;    }
.main_container > h5 { font-size: 0.8em;  }
.main_container > h6 { font-size: 0.64em; }
```

```html
<button onclick="set_font_size(16)"> normal (16px) </button>
<button onclick="set_font_size(18)"> big (18px) </button>

<div class="main_container">
  <h1>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h1>
  <h2>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h2>
  <h3>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h3>
  <h4>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h4>
  <h5>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h5>
  <h6>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h6>
  <p>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, both solutions work. The range slider is very comfortable, it can be useful in case of many more options. As for the first solution (the one without slider) I tried to change from em to rem and it doesn't work, for what reason ?

Comment: @Snorlax  because `rem` unit refer to the whole page sizing (Root Elements Measurements) as `em` is relative to parent element (here it is on all elments with the class named `main_container`

Comment: Ok I understand. I didn't know rem meant Root. Last doubt, could I replace the range slider with buttons? I am trying to do this based on your example but I cannot.

Comment: @Snorlax Added as 3th solution in answser

Answer (score 2):

The general approach to this is to add a class to one of your elements when the a button is clicked.

## Classes

Html elements can have multiple classes. These are separated by spaces
IE `<div class="main_container big green>` means that it has 3 classes, "main_container", "big" and "green"

## Css specificity

The browsers determines which css rules to apply depending on [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
when a css rules contains multiple classes it wil gain 'Specificity'
ie `.main_container {..rules..}` is less specific then `.main_container.big {..rules..}`

The rules are actually combined, any duplicate rules will be overwritten by the selector with the most specificity.

## Example

in this example we combine this.
There are css rules for `.main_container` and `.main_container.big`
the html element start with just `main_container`. when we click the button, `big` class is added. The browser then applies the additional css rules

```js
function setBig() {
  document.querySelector(".main_container").classList.add('big');
}

function removeBig() {
  document.querySelector(".main_container").classList.remove('big');
}
```

```css
/*16px Major Third 1.250 Scale Factor*/

.main_container>h1 {
  font-size: 31.25px;
}

.main_container>h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.main_container>h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main_container>h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main_container>h5 {
  font-size: 12.8px;
}

.main_container>h6 {
  font-size: 10.24px;
}

.main_container>p {
  font-size: 16px;
}


/*18px Major Third 1.250 Scale Factor*/

.main_container.big>h1 {
  font-size: 35.16px;
}

.main_container.big>h2 {
  font-size: 28.13;
}

.main_container.big>h3 {
  font-size: 22.5px;
}

.main_container.big>h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main_container.big>h5 {
  font-size: 14.4;
}

.main_container.big>h6 {
  font-size: 11.52;
}

.main_container.big>p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<button class="regular" onClick="removeBig()">Set 16px Typography</button>
<button class="regular" onClick="setBig()">Set 18px Typography</button>

<div class="main_container">
  <h1>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h1>
  <h2>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h2>
  <h3>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h3>
  <h4>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h4>
  <h5>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h5>
  <h6>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h6>
  <p>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this as below if you don't want to use classes.

But this is not recommended. using classes is better.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `:root` to set the initial size as `16px`. We can do further styling using `rem` as it is going to use **relative font size**.
If we change the `:root` font size from 16 to 18 and we use `rem` then it will automatically update every other font size for your `h1` to `h6` and `p` tags.
To change this we can use JavaScript. All we need is a click event listener attached to the buttons and pass the required font size as `'18px'` or `'24px'`.

in brief:

- define :root with initial font size
- add javascript function to change the :root font size
- use rem wherever possible in css

```js
const root = document.querySelector(':root');

const setFontSize = (fontSize) => {
  root.style.fontSize = fontSize;
}
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* 1.250 Scale Factor*/
.main_container > h1 {
  font-size: 1.953125rem; /* (1 * 1.25^3) */
}

.main_container > h2 {
  font-size: 1.5625rem; /* (1 * 1.25^2) */
}

.main_container > h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem; /* (1 * 1.25) */
}

.main_container > h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.main_container > h5 {
  font-size: 0.8rem; /* (1 / 1.25) */
}

.main_container > h6 {
  font-size: 0.64rem; /* (1 / 1.25^2) */
}

.main_container > p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="regular" onclick="setFontSize('16px')">Set 16px Typography</button>
<button class="regular" onclick="setFontSize('18px')">Set 18px Typography</button>

<div class="main_container">
  <h1>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h1>
  <h2>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h2>
  <h3>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h3>
  <h4>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h4>
  <h5>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h5>
  <h6>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h6>
  <p>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer seems to be the one that best suits my needs. Since I work with elementor it makes me comfortable to implement little code. My question is, can I replace: root with something else? This is because elementor already has its main root, so I can't replace. Obviously this all works well if I work outside elementor, also testing on JsFiddle.

Comment: You can write multiple :root, the styles are going to be work all together. Plus you can add font-size to main-container and you can use em to modify the h1 to h6 tags in a limited scope

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. But if I have two roots don't they overwrite each other ? Do we need to define them in some way as happens with html tags ?

Comment: the order or :root matters. let's say you have 3 root and in first you define color as black and in 3rd you define color as `#ddd`. so the 3rd root will **overwrite only the CSS property** It won't overwrite the whole root

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution and it works. However I am getting changes on items that shouldn't be changed, such as the main menu. Can I define root with a class or var? For example, as suggested by Mister Jojo in the comment below. `: Root {--mc_f_size: 16px; }` But I don't know how to apply it on your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add and remove classes based on your click on the buttons. I have just come up with this solution.

```js
const btnSixteen = document.querySelector('.sixteen');
const btnEighteen = document.querySelector('.eighteen');
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main_container');

btnSixteen.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  mainContainer.classList.remove('eighteenBase');
  mainContainer.classList.add('sixteenBase');
});

btnEighteen.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  mainContainer.classList.remove('sixteenBase');
 mainContainer.classList.add('eighteenBase');
})
```

```css
/*16px Major Third 1.250 Scale Factor*/
.main_container.sixteenBase > h1 {
  font-size: 31.25px;
}

.main_container.sixteenBase > h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.main_container.sixteenBase > h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main_container.sixteenBase > h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main_container.sixteenBase > h5 {
  font-size: 12.8px;
}

.main_container.sixteenBase > h6 {
  font-size: 10.24px;
}

.main_container > p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

/*18px Major Third 1.250 Scale Factor*/
.main_container.eighteenBase > h1 {
 font-size: 35.16px;
}

.main_container.eighteenBase > h2 {
 font-size: 28.13;
}

.main_container.eighteenBase > h3 {
  font-size: 22.5px;
}

.main_container.eighteenBase > h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
}

.main_container.eighteenBase > h5 {
 font-size: 14.4;
}

.main_container.eighteenBase > h6 {
  font-size: 11.52;
}

.main_container > p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<button class="regular sixteen">Set 16px Typography</button>
<button class="regular eighteen">Set 18px Typography</button>

<div class="main_container">
  <h1>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h1>
  <h2>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h2>
  <h3>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h3>
  <h4>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h4>
  <h5>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h5>
  <h6>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</h6>
  <p>Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you have h1 to h6 tags defined in html, they have their own font-sizes.
you don't have to add those styling in css file.

rather you can add two classes in css

.font16{
font-size: 16px
}

.font18{
font-size: 16px
}

and then apply those classes dynamically to the element for which you want to change font size.

eg:

```
const applyClassToElemets =(elements,className)=>{

elements.forEach(element=>element.classList.add(className))
}


const changeToSize18 = () =>{
const allH1Elements = document.querySelectorAll("h1"); 
applyClassToElemets(allH1Elements,font18)
}

const changeToSize16 = () =>{
const allH1Elements = document.querySelectorAll("h1"); 
applyClassToElemets(allH1Elements,font16)
}
```